Как в VS 2022 переместить весь редактор кода в другое место (на другой монитор)?
Мне удобно, чтоб редактор кода был на одном мониторе, всё остальное - на другом. Можно перетащить 1 вкладку с кодом в другое место (что я и сделал), но новые вкладки (которые открываешь, например, через обозреватель или по ссылке в окне вывода) всё так же открываются в основной рабочей области по центру VS, и их приходится вручную каждый раз таскать в свое отдельное окно. В VS есть пункт меню "Переместить в основную группу документов", когда находишься в своем отделённом окне. Но можно ли эту основную группу перенести из центра студии в другое место, чтоб там вкладки открывались, а не в центре?

Можно перенести все вкладки разом в отдельное окно, выбрав в контекстном меню пункт "все плавающие" на панели вкладок редактора. После этого дополнительно в новое окно нужно переместить и "обозреватель решений" - тогда открытые в нем файлы будут открываться в новых вкладках отдельного окна.
